# fetching only new rows from mysql with jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jquery/ajax load new content when available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788975/jquery-ajax-load-new-content-when-available)

i have a table named news with 3 fields i.e (id, news, time) and i have a setInterval after every 3mints to fetch news from google or any news site ....

now i want to fetch only new rows inserted after every 5 minutes...with jquery $.ajax()...how can i do that...

do i reload the whole table or there is a way to fetch only the new ones...

Comment: Check my answer for this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788975/jquery-ajax-load-new-content-when-available/2789078#2789078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a variable which stores the latest ID number for a returned row, and then include that in the AJAX call (having the PHP server-side script only return rows with an ID greater than it).

In the Calling Page

```
var latestID = 0;
...
/* Within the Variables Section for the AJAX Call */
  laterThan : latestID
...
/* Within the Success AJAX Function */
  latestID = data.highestID; /* Where "data.highestID" is the highest ID returned */
```

In the Server-Side Script being called via AJAX

```
<?php
...
/* Within the SQL Query creating the returned rows */
'WHERE
  ...
  AND `id` > '.( isset( $_GET['latestID'] ) ? (int) $_GET['latestID'] : 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to select when your time is greater than `current time - 3 minutes` and `current time`.  This will give you the newest rows that have been inserted within the last three minutes.

I don't know what database you're running, but it will be much faster to run a query every three minutes than try to process over the entire database result set.